# Something overwriting some settings set in HKCR for image files

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, photos, file-extension, filetype

**What I'm trying to achieve:** Change the file type description that is shown in the explorer file type column, when creating a new file etc.

**What I tried to do but failed:** Until now, I have been doing this for other files (it worked for `.xlsx`, `.docx`, `.pptx` and `.cmd`) like this:

1. Navigate to `HKCR\.theFileExtensionHere` in regedit
2. Check the value of `(Default)` (let's call it valueOfDefault)
3. Go to `HKCR\valueOfDefault`
4. If it has a `FriendlyTypeName` value, change it to the description I want, and if it doesn't, change the `(Default)` value to the description I want

**The problem:** When I tried to do this for `.png`, it didn't change anything. I also tried to change `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.ico` and neither worked.

**Other notes:** I think that an app (probably Windows photos, since the file icon is the Win photos one) is somehow overwriting the settings. When I add a new key to `HKCR`, for example `HKCR\.png2` and give it all the same subkeys and values that are in `HKCR\.png`, then create a file called `image.png2`, in file explorer, the file type shows up as what is set in `HKCR\pngfile\FriendlyTypeName` and the icon also changes to the one specified in `HKCR\pngfile\DefaultIcon`.

Can someone please explain to me what is happening and how can I get around it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Windows 10 or 11 ?

Comment: Decent Apps can make proper registry entries.  Two possibilities.  (1) bad App;  (2) changes you might have made.

Comment: I am using Windows 10 22H2

Answer (score 0):

It's the Microsoft Photos app that's stealing your file associations.

From the article
[How to Stop Photos App from Resetting Image File Associations?](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/stop-photos-app-taking-over-image-file-associations/)

Note : This will only work on Windows 10.

- Run `regedit`
- Position to the key
  `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\Repository\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_2022.30120.12007.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\App\Capabilities\FileAssociations`
  (the string `2022.30120.12007.0` might be different on your computer
  with a different Photos app version)
- On the right, note down the Prog ID assigned for `.jpg`,
  in my case `AppX43hnxtbyyps62jhe9sqpdzxn1790zetc`
- Go to the following registry key:
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppX43hnxtbyyps62jhe9sqpdzxn1790zetc`
- On the right, create a string value (REG_SZ) named `NoOpenWith`
- Exit the Registry Editor.